# Laravel crear un array multidimensional

Tags: php, laravel, php5, laravel-blade, php7

Tengo una query en mysql que me devuelve una fila de registros como esto, el primer campo es la `marca` y la segunda el `modelo` , lo que intento hacer con PHP es montar un array con la siguiente estructura para pasarselo a la vista de *blade* agrupado por marca y vehiculo.

*Muestra de resultados del SQL*

```
'FORD','FOCUS',1,2,3

'FORD','FOCUS',2,2,3

'FORD','FOCUS',3,1,2

'FORD','TRANSIT',1,2,3

'FORD','TRANSIT',2,2,3

'FORD','GLOBO',1,2,3
```

*El array que deseo montar es tipo este*

```
$coches = [
    'ford' => [
        focus =>  [
            valor => 1,
            valor => 2,
        ]
        TRANSIT =>  [
            valor => 1,
            valor => 2,
        ]
    ]

]
```

En cambio el array que tengo si hago un "dump" es tipo esto

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "FORD" => {#205 ▼
      +"code": "FOCUS"
      +"title": "TEST"
    }
  ]
]
```

El código que tengo en PHP es algo tipo esto

```
$sql = "SELECT xxx ... ...";

$results = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), ['id' => $id]);

$newCar = array();
$newCars = array();

foreach ($results as $cars => $car)
{
    if (empty($newCars)) {
        $newCar[$course->code] = $course;
        array_push($newCourses,$newCourse);
    }


    if (!array_key_exists('FORD',$newCourses)){
        echo '-> '. $course->code.'<br>';
    }

}
```

El último `if`, ya no me entra.

La lógica que intento hacer es crear un array por coche y modelo para pasarselo a la vista ordenado.

Comment: recorres los valores de $cars y accedes a $course??? uy que sospechoso... aqui hay alguien que cambia su problema a uno de coches???    :o)  (yo tambien lo hago)

Comment: Si...edito el post

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de las tablas que consultas? y como mencionan en el primer comentario algunas variables que ocupas en tu PHP no concuerdan.

Answer (score 1):

Como observación inicial, no vas a poder tener un arreglo con la siguiente forma:

```php
$coches = [
    'ford' => [
        'focus' =>  [
            'valor' => 1,
            'valor' => 2,
        ]
        'transit' =>  [
            'valor' => 1,
            'valor' => 2,
        ]
    ]
]
```

Pues si te fijas dentro de `focus` estás creando entradas con la misma key/clave: `valor`. Lo que sí puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```php
$coches = [
    'ford' => [
        'focus' =>  [
            'valor_1' => 1,
            'valor_2' => 2,
        ]
        'transit' =>  [
            'valor_1' => 1,
            'valor_2' => 2,
        ]
    ]
]
```

Para lograr esto puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, una es con la librería [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) de Laravel. De hecho, cualquier consulta con [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) o [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) retorna una instancia de esta clase.

---

**PD:** Dado que no concuerda la forma como pusiste tus resultados con lo usado en tu método de mapeo, voy a asumir que los registros te llegan en un arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```php
[
    ['FORD','FOCUS',1,2,3],
    ['FORD','FOCUS',1,2,3],
    ['FORD','FOCUS',1,2,3],
    ...
]
```

---

## Solución

Entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```php
// Creamos una instancia de Collection con los resultados
$results = collect(DB::select( DB::raw($sql), ['id' => $id]));

$coches = $results
    // Mapeamos el arreglo para que tenga llaves útiles
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [
            'brand'   => $item[0],
            'type'    => $item[1],
            'valor_1' => $item[2],
            'valor_2' => $item[3],
            'valor_3' => $item[4],
        ];
    })
    // Realizamos la agrupación de elementos
    ->groupBy(['brand', 'type']);
```

Esto debería de darte un arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```php
$coches = [
    'ford' => [
        'focus'   => [
            [
                'brand'   => 'ford',
                'type'    => 'focus',
                'valor_1' => 1,
                'valor_2' => 2,
                'valor_3' => 3,
            ]
        ],
        'transit' => [
            [
                'brand'   => 'ford',
                'type'    => 'transit',
                'valor_1' => 1,
                'valor_2' => 2,
                'valor_3' => 3,
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Puedes usar otros [métodos de Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) para que quede exactamente como quieres, como por ejemplo [Map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) con lo cual podrías eliminar las llaves innecesarias (`brand`, `type` ?), pero ya puedes ver que es cosa de jugar con los métodos para conseguir el resultado deseado.